# Is there any weather api provide UV index?

Tags: weather-api

I can't find any weather api providing UV index.

Does it exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (weathertrends360.com) currently have an api in private beta that has UV index.  Shoot an email to support@ and we can get you setup.

Comment: Is this a free service? Could you share a link?

Answer (score 2):

ePA has a good one.  you can access a lot of interesting data including UV index by location.

http://www.epa.gov/enviro/facts/ef_restful.html

Comment: This only works in the US. Is there a free one anywhere that works worldwide?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [OpenUV - Global UV Index Forecast API](https://www.openuv.io).

Comment: Oops I think your app is offline

Comment: Should work now

Comment: yea its working. thanks. I will run some tests with different places.